# Как реализовать изменение карты двумя игроками используя Photon Cloud и Unity

Tags: unity3d, synchronized

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу сделать простую игру, с помощью Photon. При перемещении за игроком ломаются блоки. Перемещение не пошаговое, realtime, можно двигаться в любом направлении. Игроки уже двигаются и их движение синхронировано и корректно отображается, также реализовано уничтожение плиток, но оно не синхронизировано. Я хочу чтобы изменение карты синхронизировалось между игроками. Возможно игрок1 должен передавать информацию, что он сломал такой то блок, игроку2 и у того должно это отрисовываться. Буду рад любым предложениям

Comment: Есть предложение начать писать код

Comment: Туториал по фотону https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqxzrk-pl-8